# Group by month in 6 month range sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that groups data by month, but there are some months that do not display simply because there is no data to display/group by. Is it possible to return the months and 0s for those months?

Here is my query

```
DECLARE @IMPORT_DATE AS DATETIME
SET @IMPORT_DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0), RIGHT(YEAR_MONTH_VALUE,2) 
FROM VW_CALLS
WHERE CLIENT_ID = 2
AND START_DATETIME BETWEEN DATEADD("m", -5, @IMPORT_DATE) AND @IMPORT_DATE
GROUP BY YEAR_MONTH_VALUE
ORDER BY YEAR_MONTH_VALUE
```

And it returns this:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)
740                 11
1929                12
3864                01
```

But I would like this:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)
0                   08
0                   09
0                   10
740                 11
1929                12
3864                01
```

Comment: Create a numbers table and use that to create the months to join against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `CTE` like this:

```
DECLARE @MonthStart CHAR(2) = '08'

;WITH MonthsRange AS (
   SELECT m = @MonthStart, rn = 1           

   UNION ALL   

   SELECT m = (CASE WHEN m = '12' THEN CAST('01' AS CHAR(2))
                    ELSE CAST(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CAST((CAST(m AS INT) + 1) AS CHAR(2)))) + 
                              CAST((CAST(m AS INT) + 1) AS CHAR(2)) AS CHAR(2))
               END),                       
          rn = rn + 1
   FROM MonthsRange
   WHERE rn < 6
)
SELECT *
FROM MonthsRange
```

in order to get all months you want to include in your final result set:

```
m   rn
=======
08  1
09  2
10  3
11  4
12  5
01  6
```

Now you can left join the above `CTE` against you query to get the result set you want:

```
;WITH MonthsRange AS (
 ... cte statements here
)
SELECT COALESCE(vw.cnt, 0) AS cnt, mr.m AS [Month]
FROM MonthsRange AS mr
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS cnt, RIGHT(YEAR_MONTH_VALUE,2) AS m,
          YEAR_MONTH_VALUE AS ym
   FROM VW_CALLS
   WHERE CLIENT_ID = 2 AND 
         START_DATETIME BETWEEN DATEADD("m", -5, @IMPORT_DATE) AND @IMPORT_DATE
   GROUP BY YEAR_MONTH_VALUE) AS vw ON mr.m = vw.m
ORDER BY vw.ym
```